# Beautiful Soup cannot scrape after the first div tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Please see below. I would like to scrape for the restaurant name that is in

Popeyes

Please see the image below for the HTML on this website.

Can someone please show me how I can scrape that restaurant name "Popeyes" On Python Using Beautiful Soup or any other webscraping package?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of the HTML]

Below is the code I used to scrape data, however, it stopped at  and I couldn't go further.
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client

```
# URl to web scrape from.
# in this example we web scrape graphics cards from Newegg.com
page_url = "https://www.doordash.com/store/popeyes-toronto-254846/en-CA"

# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(page_url)

# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
# as if it were a json data type.
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

page_soup.div'''
```

Comment: Please provide code as text and not as images.

Comment: Hi M Z, thanks for the reply. The HTMl seems really long when I copied it, so I thought it might be more efficient to send you the link directly.
Below is the link I am trying to scrape through, I just want the restaurant name for now, and eventually the rating and type of restaurant.
https://www.doordash.com/store/popeyes-toronto-254846/en-CA

Comment: SO is not a coding service. You must first make an attempt and if you get stuck, post your code and tell us where your problem is. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (I may make a mistake on the class name):

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_1 = 'https://www.doordash.com/store/popeyes-toronto-254846/en-CA'
sauce_1  = urllib.request.urlopen(url_1).read()
soup_1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce_1, 'lxml')     

for x in (soup_1.find_all('h1', class_ = 'sc-AnqlK keKZVr sc-jFpLkX bsGprJ')):
   print(x)
```

Let me know if this help!

Comment: Hello Matteo, Thanks for answering my question. However, I am not sure what happened, there seems to be no output from the code. I was doing a little bit of research and I think it might be some sort of dynamic content on the website. Selenium might be able to scrape it apparently but I am really new to web scraping so this is a bit too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name by speciging the 'div' class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
     }

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup.encode('utf-8')

title = soup.find(class_ = 'sc-AnqlK keKZVr sc-jFpLkX bsGprJ').get_text()

print(title)
```

I don't know if wrote right the class name  but you can copy and paste it.